# Working in 1 min / 5 min / 15 min but giving error in hourly time frame

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In Pine V5, I have used array in one indicator.
array.get() , array.set(), mattrix.get() these kind of functions are used in that code.
I am capturing values of different indicators, across different time frames, inside this array.
This indicator **working fine in** 1 min, 5 min and 15 min time frames.
But as soon as I am shifting to **hourly time frame**,
it is showing following error and indicator is not being displayed,

> Study Error -     Error on bar 0: Cannot call array methods when id of array is na.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Learning Array V3", shorttitle = "Learning Array V3", overlay = true)

_sma_source    = close

_sma01_Length  = 10
_sma02_Length  = 30
_sma03_Length  = 100
_sma04_Length  = 200

_my_array_func() =>
    array_output = array.new<float>(4, float(na))
    
    _sma10  = ta.sma(_sma_source, _sma01_Length)
    _sma30  = ta.sma(_sma_source, _sma02_Length)
    _sma100 = ta.sma(_sma_source, _sma03_Length)
    _sma200 = ta.sma(_sma_source, _sma04_Length)
   
    [_sma10, _sma30, _sma100, _sma200] 
    
    array.set(array_output, 0, _sma10)
    array.set(array_output, 1, _sma30)
    array.set(array_output, 2, _sma100)
    array.set(array_output, 3, _sma200)
    
    array_output

//========================== Getting Data inside Array  ===========

_data_mtly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1M", _my_array_func())
_data_wkly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1W", _my_array_func())
_data_daly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", _my_array_func())
_data_hrly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", _my_array_func())
_data_15mn = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", _my_array_func())

My_Array = matrix.new<float>(5, 4, na)

matuu(mtx1, _row1, _data) =>
    if not na(array.get(_data, 0))
        matrix.set(mtx1, _row1,  0, array.get(_data, 0)) // SMA10
        matrix.set(mtx1, _row1,  1, array.get(_data, 1)) // SMA50
        matrix.set(mtx1, _row1,  2, array.get(_data, 2)) // SMA100
        matrix.set(mtx1, _row1,  3, array.get(_data, 3)) // SMA200
        

matuu(My_Array, 0, _data_mtly)
matuu(My_Array, 1, _data_wkly)
matuu(My_Array, 2, _data_daly)
matuu(My_Array, 3, _data_hrly)
matuu(My_Array, 4, _data_15mn)

// Just to check what value is being stored in the Array  ....

Show_Array_Table = table.new(position.top_right, 4, 5, #000000, #000000, 1, #000000, 1)
for i = 0 to 4  
    table.cell(Show_Array_Table, 0, i, str.tostring(matrix.get(My_Array, i, 0)), text_size = size.small, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = #FFFFFF)
    table.cell(Show_Array_Table, 1, i, str.tostring(matrix.get(My_Array, i, 1)), text_size = size.small, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = #FFFFFF)
    table.cell(Show_Array_Table, 2, i, str.tostring(matrix.get(My_Array, i, 2)), text_size = size.small, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = #FFFFFF)
    table.cell(Show_Array_Table, 3, i, str.tostring(matrix.get(My_Array, i, 3)), text_size = size.small, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = #FFFFFF)
```

I don't understand how come same piece of code is working fine in 1 min / 5 min / 15 min but the same is failing in hourly TF.

Comment: without code it is hard to help you.

Comment: Hi G.Lebert, thanks for your kind revert. Pls find the code below,

Comment: No idea what I am looking at here but could it be that you iterate 5 times instead of 4?
`for i = 0 to 4` should result in 5 roundtrips and not 4 as could result in the missing id of array? Just shoot in the dark

Comment: Thanks Denny Mueller for trying to help me out. Loop iteration for 5 times is not the cause of this problem. I checked it by editing that part but the isuues remained as it is.

Comment: Thanks G.Lebret for giving me this detail revert.  I tried the solution you suggested but could not sort this out. I draw this conclusion that it is not possible to catch 15min TF indicator values into an array when chart TF is Hourly. By the by I am not only failing to catch values in Hourly TF but also failing if the chart has less number of candles. In less number of candles ( like monthly option chart ) similar error message is coming.  G.Lebret  you are quite knowledgeable in Pine hence request you to give it another try, if you can get some free time. Thanks a lot !

Comment: G.Lebert, kindly note I am catching a Float array whereas request.security_lower_tf can be used with simple int expression only. Otherwise this could work ...if timeframe.period == "60"
    _data_15mn = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "15", my_array_func())
else
    _data_15mn = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", _my_array_func())

Answer (score 0):

in your script, you ask for those request.security :

```
_data_mtly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1M", _my_array_func())
_data_wkly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1W", _my_array_func())
_data_daly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", _my_array_func())
_data_hrly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", _my_array_func())
_data_15mn = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", _my_array_func())
```

So if you set your timeframe above 15min (30 min or 1 hour), your `_data_15mn` will create problems.
In pinescript to use request.security on a lower timeframe, you use a special function (`request.security_lower_tf`) that send you back an array (because there are several values in the 15min timeframe when you are on the 1 hour timeframe on your chart).

From the pinescript manual :

> Scripts not written specifically to use lower timeframe data, when
> they are published for a broader audience, should ideally include
> protection against running them on chart timeframes where
> request.security() would be accessing lower timeframes than the
> chart’s, as it will not produce reliable results in those cases. See
> the Comparing timeframes section for a code example providing
> error-checking to avoid just that.

The link to deal with the control of timeframe here :
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Timeframes.html#pagetimeframes-comparingtimeframes